# problem getting a json multi dimensional array to work with jquery getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

i'm using jquery.getJson() to retrieve a json object created by my php script.

it works if i remove the locations array. however i need the locations array to populate a combobox.

my formatted json is below. any suggestions how i can get this to work with one json query instead of 2.

```
{ "ContactID" : "1", "CustomerID" : "1", "FirstName" : "john", "LastName" : "smith", "Position" : "General Manager", "ContactNumber" : "234523455", "FaxNumber" : "235235234", "LocationSelected" : "1", "Default" : "default", locations : {0 : { "addressID" : "1" , "description" : "Street Address" }}}
```

i also tried it like this

```
{ "ContactID" : "1", "CustomerID" : "1", "FirstName" : "john", "LastName" : "smith", "Position" : "General Manager", "ContactNumber" : "234523455", "FaxNumber" : "235235234", "LocationSelected" : "1", "Default" : "default", locations : [{ "addressID" : "1" , "description" : "Street Address" }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like that. Just make sure that you are using correct mime type.

[change mime type of output in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152006/change-mime-type-of-output-in-php)

[Which JSON content type do I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Maybe you should also use quote the locations key

```
... "locations" : [{ "addressID" : "1" , "description" : "Street Address" }]}
```

You could also use JSON-functions of PHP to generate the JSON.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem..
[Json retrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927170/how-to-retrieve-key-and-value-from-json-string)
 and 
[this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926716/how-to-send-an-arraymultidimensional-associative-and-some-varaibles-together-t)